Apache Kafka: Producer TimeoutException Failed to allocate memory within the configured max blocking time 60000 ms
I am having issue related to producer sending messages to kafka. With my message being sent around ~100kb it was working but recently it is having issue like below

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to allocate memory within the configured max blocking time 60000 ms.
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to allocate memory within the configured max blocking time 60000 ms.

I don't know what's wrong with my settings. Can you guys take a look at the settings and help me with this problem?
This is my producer config.
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory(KafkaContextConfig kafkaContextConfig) {
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(kafkaContextConfig.getEnabled())) {
            final Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
            config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaContextConfig.getBootstrapServers());
            config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
            config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
            if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(kafkaContextConfig.getSaslEnabled())) {
                config.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, kafkaContextConfig.getSaslSecurityProtocolConfig());
                config.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, kafkaContextConfig.getSaslMechanism());
                config.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, kafkaContextConfig.getSaslJaasConfig());
            }
            return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

Thanks for your support!

From error message it states that producer is failing to allocate memory for the message within max blocking time.In detail producer will wait for max.block.ms to allocate enough memory for message in buffer.Try to increase the parameter max.block.ms, also consider increasing buffer.memory value.
